# Star Wars: Battlefront II EA Trailer - Who is the figure in red giving Versio orders?

Tags: star-wars, video-games, trailer, star-wars-battlefront

** *WARNING POSSIBLE SPOILERS AHEAD* **

Judging by the color and style of his apparel, I am guessing he is perhaps a member (or ex-member) of the Imperial Guard. Possibly the Captain. Because the majority of the single player storyline will take place after the destruction of the second Death Star and the Emperor's demise, it is not unlikely that the Captain of his Imperial Guard would be left in some position of High Imperial Command. (Admittedly unlikely however, that he would be given command of a ship. Imperial Guards aren't trained for naval command.)

Also I believe I have identified his species. Judging by the pale skin and black rhombus-like line tattoo, he is Rattataki. However he is only seen through what appears to be some sort of holoprojection device (as seen by the static and glitches that can be noticed), perhaps projecting the image of his head over a robotic body. Therefore the pale skin could simply be the blue tint of the holo, but the tattoo is still present and I stand by my claim.

It's not *entirely* impossible either that he is some type of Sith, however plenty of other Star Wars stories have already bent (if not flat out broken) the rule of two. Ex: The Force Unleashed Series, Star Wars Rebels, Mara Jade (Multiple Appearances), etc. | Which leads me to believe EA may not want to add their game to that list with the overdone plot.

So who and what is he? Any help on this matter or additional theories would be greatly appreciated, many thanks to those who contribute.

Comment: Since the game is not out yet, and there doesn't appear to be any additional official info on this, this might fall under our ["questions about future works are off-topic"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5188/70236) policy, as it is essentially only theories and opinions.

Comment: I don't know enough about Shattered Empire/Battlefront 2 to be able to give a full and proper answer, but I think this guy may have cracked it: https://twitter.com/Truly_Defective/status/853597151125020672 maybe someone who does have a better grasp of the Shattered Empire comic might be able to answer this properly?

Comment: @Galifreyan but *the trailer* has been released...

Comment: "This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy within the scope defined in the help center." Pretty sure Star Wars is science fiction mates...

Comment: You're right about SW, but please read the question that @Gallifreyan has included above. As soon as the game comes out, you'll most likely get your answer. Until then we've only got *speculation, theories and opinions* to go on - this site prefers facts.

Comment: He is no Rattataki. In the Star Wars Battlefront II Gameplay Trailer, it is clear that it is a hologram (possibly a brought-back-from-the-dead) version of Emperor Palpatine.

Comment: OK updating my earlier comment. Before he died, in the event of a major disaster (like his death), Palpatine gave holographic orders that he places in suits of red armor (the red figure in the trailer). He wanted to give clear orders before his death.

Comment: @Longshanks Just because the site prefers facts doesn't mean I can't speculate on things and make theories. But if you'd like to correct my assumption that the advertisements about said site are in fact lies, please do so now and I will find the proper site where my unique theories are accepted.

Comment: This was revealed via new trailers (and then by the release of the game itself) several months after this question was asked, and I've got the answer ready with proper reference materials if it's reopened.

Answer (score 6):

The figure in red is a [sentinel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sentinel_(Contingency)), a type of droid that gave out orders to Imperial commanders after Palpatine's death.[image: Sentinel droid] They were used to direct and brief high-ranking Imperials on initiating  [Operation: Cinder](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Operation%3A_Cinder).

Comment: and yes, both they and the single player campaign are canon